# Show the table from MySQL without having to code every column name

Tags: php, mysql

for the sake of my admin page, I'm trying to just show the table contents from the MYSQL database. However, I don't want to prepare HTML for every table that I want to show, so I got this script from one of the posts here on stackoverflow.

It works fine, however, it always omits the first record from any table, any suggestions how to fix it?

```
function display_data($data) {
$output = '<table>';
foreach($data as $key => $var) {
    $output .= '<tr>';
    foreach($var as $k => $v) {
        if ($key === 0) {
            $output .= '<td><strong>' . $k . '</strong></td>';
        } else {
            $output .= '<td>' . $v . '</td>';
        }
    }
    $output .= '</tr>';
}
$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
```

}

The $data comes from associative array after fetching the table and putting it into the associative array.

This is what comes in in array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [email] => ppronin@gmail.com [login] => ppronin@gmail.com [phone] => 77059907777 [password] => $2y$12$amBi4JClzNjOFspBCdi8Vu3o/ETGUdHZKOLKkZDpQkFhs7T0/LOTO [active] => 0 [date_create] => 2020-03-26 15:43:42 [family_name] => Пронин [name] => Павел [role] => 9 [estatus] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [email] => ppronin@ikeen.com [login] => ppronin@ikeen.com [phone] => 7059907777 [password] => $2y$12$on7Z4L2nv9l28qjG/9FA3eZqI7NvjTRuySUJelWWo1/J2i4t9uWka [active] => 0 [date_create] => 2020-05-20 11:19:14 [family_name] => Пронин2 [name] => Павел2 [role] => 0 [estatus]
```

But that's what it shows

[image]

As you may see the first record is omitted. Thank you in advance, I've searched on google but could not find a viable solution, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Found that, please use if you have same problem, solution from Axel Arnold Bangert - Herzogenrath 201

```
function display_data($data) {
    $output = "<table class='table'>";
    foreach($data as $key => $var) {
        //$output .= '<tr>';
        if($key===0) {
            $output .= '<tr>';
            foreach($var as $col => $val) {
                $output .= "<td>" . $col . '</td>';
            }
            $output .= '</tr>';
            foreach($var as $col => $val) {
                $output .= '<td>' . $val . '</td>';
            }
            $output .= '</tr>';
        }
        else {
            $output .= '<tr>';
            foreach($var as $col => $val) {
                $output .= '<td>' . $val . '</td>';
            }
            $output .= '</tr>';
        }
    }
    $output .= '</table>';
    echo $output;
}
```